# Java: Print array elements

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I need to print the array elements in increments of 10 each line...

```
import java.util.*;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double alpha[] = new double[50];

        //Initialize the first 25 elements of the array (int i=0; i<25; i++)//
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            alpha[i]= i * i;
        }

        //Initialize the last 25 elements of the array (i=25; i<50; i++)//
        for(int i = 25; i < 50; i++) {
            alpha[i]= 3 * i;
        }

        //Print the element of the array
        System.out.println ( "The values are: " );

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            System.out.println ( alpha[i] );
        }

        //Print method to display the element of the array
        void print(double m_array[]) {
            for(int i =1; i <= m_array.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(m_array[i-1] +" ");
                if(i%10==0)
                    System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assuming this if statement is my problem...if it is exactly what am I missing I tried the printf but that didn't work...

Comment: Besides that you could simply do `System.out.println();` instead of `System.out.print("\n");`, what is your problem? What is the result you get?

Comment: You put the `void print(double)` method inside of the main method. Move that outside the main method and call it from inside the main method with `print(alpha);`

Comment: Why the loop is going till `m_array;length`? Isn't this suppose to throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @nIcEcOw No because they are accessing the value with `m_array[i-1]`

Comment: @Dando18: Ahha, that is a good point :-) I just looked at the `if block` and assumed it to be the case. Also, after formatting I realized the `print` method inside the `main` :-) Good point :-)

Comment: Ok easy enough to put the print method outside of the main but I still need to show ten of each of those numbers on each line I print....ideas?  I'm printing all the numbers on separate lines...grrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double alpha[] = new double[50];

        // Initialize the first 25 elements of the array (int i=0; i<25; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            alpha[i] = i * i;
        }

        // Initialize the last 25 elements of the array (i=25; i<50; i++)
        for (int i = 25; i < 50; i++) {
            alpha[i] = 3 * i;
        }

        System.out.println("The values are: ");

        // Print the element of the array
        print(alpha);

    }

    // Print method to display the element of the array
    private static void print(double m_array[]) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= m_array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(m_array[i-1] + " ");
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> The values are:
>
> 0.0 1.0 4.0 9.0 16.0 25.0 36.0 49.0 64.0 81.0
>
> 100.0 121.0 144.0 169.0 196.0 225.0 256.0 289.0 324.0 361.0
>
> 400.0 441.0 484.0 529.0 576.0 75.0 78.0 81.0 84.0 87.0
>
> 90.0 93.0 96.0 99.0 102.0 105.0 108.0 111.0 114.0 117.0
>
> 120.0 123.0 126.0 129.0 132.0 135.0 138.0 141.0 144.0 147.0

Comment: Very nice Daniel I never would have thought to print it outside of the main but it totally makes sense...

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It solved one of my problems the other is a boolean check = false.  I'm searching, within the array for a number and if it exists I would like to print that I've found it or that It doesn't exist...

Comment: I will definitely check that box for you...and I know that the if statement needs to be outside of the for...I'm just confused where I should put it because when I put it in both each number had a The number 4 has been found!!! fifty times lol

Comment: Declare the variable before, outside the "for". And then, inside the "for", you put the "if" statement. Then, outside the "for" (after) you print the message.

Comment: I put that code in another answer because it didn't fit in the comments here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Array {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        double alpha[] = new double[50];

        // Initialize the first 25 elements of the array (int i=0; i<25; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            alpha[i] = i * i;
        }

        // Initialize the last 25 elements of the array (i=25; i<50; i++)
        for (int i = 25; i < 50; i++) {
            alpha[i] = 3 * i;
        }

        System.out.println("The values are: ");

        // Print the element of the array
        print(alpha);

        double number = 4.0;
        if (hasElement(alpha, number)) {
            System.out.println("The number " + number + " has been found!!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The number " + number + " doesn't exist");
        }

    }

    // Print method to display the element of the array
    private static void print(double m_array[]) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= m_array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(m_array[i-1] + " ");
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasElement(double m_array[], double element) {
        for (double e : m_array) {
            if (e == element) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```